# How python freeze compiles all the code objects together into single executable

Tags: python, freeze

I know that freeze.py find out all required modules and write *.c file for each module and the content of *.c is the code object as string. And then a Makefile is created to compile those files with gcc.

What I cannot figure out is what's the magic of the makefile to compile all those *.c files together into one executable.

Why gcc? Is this because python interpreter is written in c?

All I know that is the content of the *.c files are byte code instructions for python. How the makefile integrates those instructions with python interpreter?

Thanks!

Comment: After 3 times reading your question, I still got no clue what the problem is

Comment: @Amin, thanks for reading. I want to know how does the freeze.py work. the official document says that it generates *.c file for all related modules. And what confuses me is how those *.c file linked together into a single executable by the makefile which is also generated by freeze.py.